# div moves into another div on windows resize

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

When I resize window, the right floated div moves into centered Div. How do I stick the right floated div on the right so it doesn't move when window is resized?

```
<div id="topbar">
    <div id="wrapper960">
     Navigation menu
    </div>
    <div id="search">
     Searchbox
    </div>
</div>

#topbar{width:100%; vertical-aligh:middle; }
#wrapper960{width:960px; margin:0px auto; min-height:25px;}
#search{float:right; margin:-25px 0px 0px 0px}
```

Comment: search is a .net control and when browser renders it, it falls off the topbar and so i am using -ve margin to bring it up and have it stay inside topbar.

Comment: I recommend using JSFiddle. I made [**This JSFiddle for you.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseMoskal/GHBLG/) It will allow folks here to bumble around with your problem, and post back a solution for you.

Comment: Put it inside `wrapper960`.

Comment: Here's a fiddle showing things a little more clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/GHBLG/3/

Comment: What you're seeing there is the expected behavior for a float. Please describe more clearly what the desired behavior is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediately, I noticed in `#topbar{width:100%; vertical-aligh:middle; }`, you have misspelled `vertical-align` as `vertical-aligh`.

Despite that, as a whole, I recommend making your code more semantically descriptive of the content you're trying to express, following more closely modern web coding standards.

### I made [*This JSFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseMoskal/GHBLG/2/) for you, in hopes this represents something close to the navigation bar you're looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseMoskal/GHBLG/2/

Good luck friend! *Happy Coding! //Chase.*

### Edit:

To be more explicit in this answer instead of just JSFiddle, I think it would be nice to represent your navigation bar as an unordered list, with the search box at the end.

```
<ul class="topbar">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <div class="search">Search</div>
</ul>
```

As for the CSS in JSFiddle, I `list-style:none;` the unordered list; I `display:inline-block;` the list items (`float:left;` would be a perfectly acceptable and perhaps more cross-browser way to do it as well); and I `float:right;` the search box. The `::after` psuedo-element on the list clears the float'd list contents, and the `width:100%;max-width:960px;` allows your bar to dynamically squish down in size for smaller windows. **Everything else in the CSS is simply for fanciness.** *//Chase.*